# CSS - How to show only a % of the top div with two identicals divs stacked over each other

Tags: html, css, colors

I have two divs stacked over each other containing the exact same text. My bottom div is in grey and my top div, colored in red. I'm trying to find a way to color the text by a pre-determined %, i.e only show a certain % of the top colored div and hide the rest of it to have the text in mixed color. I want to be able to have a letter that could be, for instance, colored half in grey and half in red. At the right of this letter, everything would be grey at its left, red.

So far, I've been playing around with a small trial fixed `width` of `x pixels` and `overflow-x:hidden;`. However, it breaks the text into words and display the first `x pixels` of each word with each word on a single new line. It also fails if the given `width` is greater than the `width` of the first word. Is there a way to accomplish what I want with CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/kaj88maw/

```
<div class="text-grey">
    We love Stack Overflow
</div>
<div class="text-color">
    We love Stack Overflow
</div>

.text-grey, .text-color{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.text-grey{
    color: grey;
}

.text-color{
    color: red;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with    `white-space:nowrap;`

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/kaj88maw/7/